# LINQ - can't create with WHERE condition

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following method:

```
    public DataTable.DataTablesPage<DataTable.UserModel> DataTableUserListByAttendees(int geoArea, int CurrentUserID)
    {
        var result = from i in _dbContext.Users
                     where i.GeographicalAreas.Any(p => p.GeoAreaID == geoArea)
                     select new DataTable.UserModel()
                     {
                         ID = i.ID,
                         Company = i.Company,
                         DCMember = (i.UserId != null),
                         FirstName = i.FirstName,
                         LastName = i.LastName
                     };
```

}

it works fine, but it returns entities that dont have the geoArea proeprty set.

```
    public DataTable.DataTablesPage<DataTable.UserModel> DataTableUserListByAttendees(int? geoArea, int CurrentUserID)
    {
        var result = from i in _dbContext.Users
                     where i.GeographicalAreas.Any(p => p.GeoAreaID == geoArea)
                     select new DataTable.UserModel()
                     {
                         ID = i.ID,
                         Company = i.Company,
                         DCMember = (i.UserId != null),
                         FirstName = i.FirstName,
                         LastName = i.LastName
                     };
```

}

How can I change the query so that it returns only entities that have their geoArea property set (aka is not null).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
where (geoArea == null) || i.GeographicalAreas.Any(p => p.GeoAreaID == geoArea)
```

or conditionally add the where to the query

Answer (score 3):

That should be

```
where geoArea == null || i.GeographicalAreas.Any(p => p.GeoAreaID == (int)geoArea)
```